# Dynamically update text nodes in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm trying to update the text nodes in xml based on the check if it matches a certain pattern

in xslt 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="CheckAndReplace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="&#129;"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="CheckAndReplace">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="pattern"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="regexp:match( $text, $pattern, 'gi' )">
            <xsl:copy-of select="regexp:replace( $text, $pattern, 'gi','*' )"
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<Root>
 <Name> Kabir </Name>
 <Id> &#129; </Id>
</Root>
```

Here the request has ID tag which matches my pattern and that needs to be replaced

Result Required:

```
<Root>
 <Name> Kabir </Name>
 <Id> * </Id>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your first question here, harish. Looks like @michael.hor257k has answered your original question -- don't forget to accept the answer if they did! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no regex in XSLT 1.0. If your goal is to replace all occurrences of the `&#129;` character with a `*` then try:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#129;', '*')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael,that helped me replacing. But one issue i have is that: I have a file (xml) which contains the list of special characters (or patterns in array) which i have to test against the input request. If any of the pattern (in the file) matches the text content of incoming request :then i should replace them with '*' and the other nodes should be as is.  Could you please suggest me in this.

Comment: Please post a new question and show an example of this file, along with your input and the expected output - see [mcve].

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have created another question for the issue ( with title: Dynamically replace matched special characters)